# What feelings does placing a minor chord in different places in a chord progression create?

Tags: theory, piano, chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

For example, let's take the common major progression of I-V-vi-IV chords. How would the feeling of the overall song differ if:

- The vi chord was the first chord of the progression
- The vi chord was the second chord of the progression
- The vi chord was the resolving chord?

And on a similar vein, does only the placement of one chord change the vibe, or does the placement of all the chords matter (Again, I-V-vi-IV as an example)?

Comment: Time is relative. If you give us a simple progression like that, without *any* context (including the duration of each chord and how many times does it possibly repeat), the "base" context will be: 1. the first chord is the "down beat" - or maybe not?; 2. every chord has the same duration (or maybe not?!?). With a simple progression as yours, you're giving the listener complete freedom: we could even consider the "vi" chord as "ii", with a progression like IV-I-ii-I, with the downbeat on the second or fourth chord.

Comment: Ahh okay, so rather than the actual chords, it depends more on the rhythm of it? I'm still a beginner, so I don't know quite a lot about rhythms. Any resources you can direct me to where I could learn more about this stuff?

Comment: time is *everything* in music: without time (and, obviously, time relations), music wouldn't exist, including music that is considered "timeless" - or "beatless". The point is that music is a extremely broad matter that is mostly based on the *variation* of events in time in multiple given context. Simply put, amount and frequency at given time positions and relations: how long some "sounds" last and/or how "strong" they are related to the others. And, even considering that, there are some ambiguities. Take for instance the Prelude from the Bach's E partita for violin. ->

Comment: -> That piece has *lots* of rhythm challenges, and if you're not accustomed to it as a *player* (hence, after *deeply* studying, practicing it and 
understanding* it), you'll probably have some doubts about its rhythm, including harmonic relations. I suggest you to read [this very interesting post](https://www.ethanhein.com/wp/2020/rhythmic-ambiguity-in-the-bach-e-major-partita-prelude/) and listen through its examples (even if you might not like some of them). The very concepts of time, beat and rhythm could be ambiguous, especially if not considered within the context of the whole piece.

Comment: Have you tried all your suggestions? What did they do for you?

Comment: Thanks for the link musicamante! I'll check it out later today. The concept of time signatures will take a bit to wrap my head around, but I've got the basics (2/4, 3/4, 4/4 and 6/8) down.
Tim, I'm not sure if you're referring to me or musicamante. If it's for me, then I haven't done anything yet as I just saw them. I'll go through it all later, and then I'll move onto actually practicing everything so I understand it better!

Comment: @IzzyDev The question was closed because it asked about "feelings," but let me ask a different question for you: "Does the order of chords matter?" Yes, absolutely. What happens when you change the order of words in a sentence? "Bob saw Billy at the grocery store." If you say "Billy saw Bob," the meaning changes. Even if you say "At the grocery store, Bob saw Billy," the meaning is the same but the impact is different. By asking about chords in a progression, you're already placing your question in a context; a language that grew and evolved over centuries of Western practice... ->

Comment: -> If you were to ask the same question in Medieval Europe, the answer would be "whaddaya mean chords"? (And if you asked Plato, he'd talk your ear off about 'feelings,' but would be more concerned with your collection of notes.) So yes, as soon as you start talking about I, V, etc, there is a role that each one is accustomed to play in patterns that have been ingrained over centuries. Subverting these conventions can create interest, but you would probably have a hard time throwing them out entirely. ->

Comment: -> It sounds like you're new to music theory in general; I like https://www.musictheory.net/ as a "covers the basics" resource, though it can be confusing. There are probably great youtube tutorials. Remember, though, that music is something you make! The best way to learn music theory is to "play along." If you're already playing chords, you're already using music theory without knowing it, and learning the theory will just help explain to you *why* things "feel" the way they do.

Comment: Thank you so much @AndyBonner! I know a little bit about music theory, but I wanted to get a more professional opinion on this. I'll check out the website you linked to. I am quite interested in learning different patterns and trends, so hopefully, this helps start off that journey!